# Doughnut chart from Chart.js, custom legend and call of original handler not works as expected

Tags: chart.js

Trying to make a custom handler with call of original handler as told in subject.

```php
            legend_labels_options: {
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            onClick: function (e, legendItem) {
                console.log(e, legendItem)
                Chart.defaults.doughnut.legend.onClick.call(this, e, legendItem)
            },
            labels: {
                generateLabels: chart => {
                    if (chart.data.datasets.length > 0) {
                        let options = {}

                        return chart.data.datasets[0].data.map((mapping, index) => {
                            options['fillStyle'] = chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index]

                            if (chart.canvas.id === 'group-hours-chart') {
                                options['text'] = this.minutesToHMS(mapping)

                                return options
                            }

                            options['text'] = chart.data.labels[index]

                            return options
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So, the legendItem in onClick custom handler consists just only of this properties (for somehow there no index or datasetIndex property):

```
fillStyle: (...)
text: (...)
```

So I can't implement hide logic there.

call of

```
Chart.defaults.doughnut.legend.onClick.call(this, e, legendItem)
```

makes nothing (absolutely no errors neither output).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please paste the full code, and what functionality you are trying to achieve, custom legend?

Comment: @KunalKhivensara yep, custom legends label formatting. full code is big enough i think, what concrete place of code do you need?

Comment: Just need to have a working code to debug the issue, but nvm let's see if anyone else can look at the given code and help.

Comment: @KunalKhivensara I have dougnut which extends another chart, which extends something else with mixins..so i don't think that full code will be working - there is need to make it "jsfiddlable" :(

Comment: Yeah, Making a fiddle is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the issue. I've already tried that but for some reasons that not worked, but now (maybe app.js was cached) that is what you have to do: you should pass 'index' property in 'generatelabels' like this:

```
   legend_labels_options: {
        display: true,
        position: 'left',
        onClick: function (e, legendItem) {
            console.log(e, legendItem)
            Chart.defaults.doughnut.legend.onClick.call(this, e, legendItem)
        },
        labels: {
            generateLabels: chart => {
                if (chart.data.datasets.length > 0) {
                    let options = {}

                    return chart.data.datasets[0].data.map((mapping, index) => {
                        options['fillStyle'] = chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index]

                        if (chart.canvas.id === 'group-hours-chart') {
                            options['text'] = this.minutesToHMS(mapping)

                            return options
                        }

                        options['text'] = chart.data.labels[index]
                        options['index'] = index

                        return options
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```